# jQuery - Fill in missing days of week value from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to display openings-hours that a registered user has filled in during sign-up:

This is the '`value`' & its stored this way in the DB:

```
[
{"day":"Maandag","daylabel":"Maandag","fromtime":"15:30","fromtimelabel":"3:30 pm","totime":"22:00","totimelabel":"10:00 pm"},
{"day":"Dinsdag","daylabel":"Dinsdag","fromtime":"15:30","fromtimelabel":"3:30 pm","totime":"22:00","totimelabel":"10:00 pm"},
{"day":"Donderdag","daylabel":"Donderdag","fromtime":"15:30","fromtimelabel":"3:30 pm","totime":"22:00","totimelabel":"10:00 pm"},
{"day":"Vrijdag","daylabel":"Vrijdag","fromtime":"15:30","fromtimelabel":"3:30 pm","totime":"22:00","totimelabel":"10:00 pm"},
{"day":"Zaterdag","daylabel":"Zaterdag","fromtime":"09:30","fromtimelabel":"9:30 am","totime":"+00:00","totimelabel":"12:00 am (next day)"},
{"day":"Zondag","daylabel":"Zondag","fromtime":"09:30","fromtimelabel":"9:30 am","totime":"+00:00","totimelabel":"12:00 am (next day)"}
]
```

This is my function to parse the `value`:

```
config.profile.core.parseAvailability = function(value){
  if(value){
    try {
        var availabilityDays = JSON.parse(value);
        $jq.each(availabilityDays, function(index, day) {
            $jq('#availability').append('<div class="col-sm-5">'+day['daylabel']+'</div><div class="col-sm-7">'+day['fromtime']+' - '+day['totime']+'</div>');
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
  }
};
```

And this is the way it's displayed on the page:

[image]

**The problem:**

As you maybe can see, the day for Wednesday (*in dutch 'woensdag' between 'dinsdag' & 'donderdag'*) is missing because its not filled in on purpose (its possible to be closed on a specific day). And because that day is not stored, i can not display it.

Ho do i display the missing day(s) with empty values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than looping over the data you've *got*, loop over the data you *want* then display what matches it

```
var days = ['Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag'];
var availabilityDays = JSON.parse(value);

for (var day of days) {
    var details = availabilityDays.find(function (detail) {
        return detail.day == day;
    });

    var detailsText = '';

    if (details) {
        detailsText = details['fromtime']+' - '+details['totime']
    }

    $jq('#availability').append('<div class="col-sm-5">'+day+'</div><div class="col-sm-7">' + detailsText + '</div>');
}
```